# Necessary and sufficient conditions for a Nonlinear Matrix inequality

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, functions, vector-analysis

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f(x)\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth function. Consider a  symmetric matrix $M(x)\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, whose elements are smooth. I am trying to prove the following **(dont know if this holds)**:

$$f(x)^\top M(x) f(x)\leq 0 \iff M(x) \leq 0.$$

What have I tried:

1. Method(1)

   We need to prove:

   - Case(a): $ M(x) \leq 0 \implies f(x)^\top M(x) f(x)\leq 0$.
   - Case(b): $f(x)^\top M(x) f(x)\leq 0 \implies  M(x) \leq 0$.

   Case (a) is trivial. In Case (b), if we consider the senariao when
   inequality holds strictly, then $f(x)^\top M(x) f(x)< 0 \implies 
   M(x) < 0$. However, in the event the equality holds i.e., $f(x)^\top
   M(x) f(x)= 0$, then one or more of the following hold:

   1. $M(x)=0$
   2. $M(x)f(x) = 0$, i.e., $f(x)$ is in the left null space of $M(x)$.
   3. $M(x)^\top f(x) = 0$, i.e., $f(x)$ is in the right null space of $M(x)$.

   I am stuck here.
2. Method (2): Since $M(x)$ is symmetric, $LU$ decomposition holds with
   $L=U^\top$. Hence, let $M(x)=L^\top(x)D(x) L(x)$ with $D$ as a
   block diagonal matrix, then we have $$(L(x)f(x))^\top D(x) (L(x)f(x))\leq
   0$$ Again I am stuck!

Comment: Where are your quantifiers? Do you want to have $\forall f : ( f(x)^\top M f(x) \le 0 \;\Leftrightarrow\; M(x) \le 0)$ or $(\forall f :  f(x)^\top M f(x) \le 0) \;\Leftrightarrow\; M(x) \le 0$. And what do you mean by $M(x) \le 0$?

Answer (score 1):

I constantly tell my students matrix language is an abomination when theory is what is to be understood, and you are the quintessential example of what I mean. Having said that, the exercise is **either** *trivially false* or *trivially true.*

**False.** If you mean that for some $f$ the inequality $f(x)^\intercal M(x) f^(x) \leq 0$ implies $M(x)$ to be negative semidefinite, consider the constant functions (hence smooth, even analytic) $M =\left[\begin{matrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{matrix}\right]$ and $f=(1, 0)^\intercal.$

**True.** If you mean that the relation $f(x)^\intercal M(x) f(x) \leq 0$ for all smooth functions $f$ implies $M(x)$ to be negative semidefinite, then simply consider $f$ *constant* functions and you obtain the definition of negative semidefinite.